# Why does my TSX import read as declared but never read when I try and pass it to the Jest render method?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, next.js13

I have a Jest test file which contains a simple import of one TSX component in my nextjs 13 site. When I attempt to provide the component as a TSX tag I get the error

> "'Properties' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did
> you mean 'typeof Properties'?ts(2749)"

And the import itself shows

> "'Properties' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) "

However when it is passed without the syntax for making it TSX i.e. opening and closing < /> the Properties import is suddenly used and recognised. The import itself is showing the signature of a typescript JSX.Element so it is seemingly correct. What could be the cause of this?

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Properties from "../src/app/[locale]/properties/page"
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

describe("PropertiesPage", () => {
    it("renders a results page", () => {
        const meme = render(<Properties/>) // < fails to recognise import

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm just an idiot and I marked the file as ts rather than tsx